# Fonts in LibreOfficePortable\Data\fonts are not used

Tags: windows-10, fonts, libreoffice, portable-apps

Having installed the portable LibreOffice, I found the `fonts` folder with the file named `add_fonts_here.txt`.

So I put some TrueType fonts in there and restarted LibreOffice.
However the fonts are not found it seems.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was that LibreOffice actually did not quit when I told it to quit (although the window had closed):
I found some related processes in the task list.

After manually stopping those and restarting LibreOffice, the fonts were no longer missing!